# Meaning of $c_1(\mathfrak s)^2$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes, low-dimensional-topology

I have a negative definite 4-manifold $X$ with a rational homology sphere boundary $Y$. For simplicity, I'm assuming also that $H_1(X)=0$. Given a spin^c-structure $\mathfrak s$ on $X$ that restricts to $\mathfrak t$ on $Y$, there is an upper bound for the Heegaard Floer homology correction term
$$ 4 d(Y, {\frak t}) \geq c_1({\frak s})^2 + b_2(X).$$

My question is how should I interpret $c_1({\frak s})^2$ here?

I've seen in practice that by thinking of $H^2(X) \subset Hom(H_2(X);\mathbb{Z})$ the intersection form of $X$ induces a rational valued pairing on $H^2(X)$. Then $c_1(\frak s)^2$ is computed by squaring $c_1({\frak s})$ using this pairing. However, I'm not sure what the topological interpretation on $c_1({\frak s})^2$ should be to make this the correct thing to do.

I suspect there must be something simple that I'm missing here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $c_1(\mathfrak{s})$ is the first Chern class of the determinant line bundle associated to $\mathfrak{s}$.

Comment: So how should I interpret the square in the case that $X$ has boundary? The first Chern class lives in $H^2(X)$ and hence its square lives in $H^4(X)=0$. I don't see why that should give me $c_1({\frak s})^2$ a rational number, which is what occurs without explanation in the literature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if how useful this untimely answer is to you at this moment, but anyway an answer:

Start with $c_1(\mathfrak{s})\in H^2(X;\mathbb{Z})$. Note that the boundary of $X$ is a rational homology 3-sphere, so $H^2(\partial X;\mathbb{Q})=H^1(\partial X;\mathbb{Q})=0$, which implies from the LES of the pair $(X,\partial X)$ that $H^2(X;\mathbb{Q})\cong H^2(X,\partial X;\mathbb{Q})$. And the intersectio form $Q_X$ of $X$ takes as its input as an element in $H^2(X,\partial X;\mathbb{Q})$, which we can safely identify with $H^2(X;\mathbb{Q})$ by the above isomorphism.

Note that the cup product induces a map $H^2(X,\partial X)\otimes H^2(X,\partial X)\to H^4(X,\partial X)$, whose target allows an evaluation with the fundamental class $[X,\partial X]\in H_4(X,\partial X)$ of $X$, so $Q_X$ makes sense for a 4-manifold with boundary. Also note that the intersection pairing reduces to a pairing on free part of $H^2(X,\partial X;\mathbb{Z})$, which can be just tensored by $\mathbb{Q}$ to yield the intersection pairing $Q_X:H^2(X,\partial X;\mathbb{Q})\otimes H^2(X,\partial X;\mathbb{Q})\to \mathbb{Q}$ (using $\mathbb{Q}$ coefficient.)

So the upshot is, $c_1(\mathfrak{s})^2$ in this context is just $Q_X(\overline{c_1(\mathfrak{s})},\overline{c_1(\mathfrak{s})})$ where the entry $\overline{c_1(\mathfrak{s})}$ is the reduction of $c_1(\mathfrak{s})$ under the map $H^2(X;\mathbb{Z})\to H^2(X;\mathbb{Q})$.

Actually a bit of similar work shows that $c_1(\mathfrak{s})^2\in\mathbb{Q}$ makes sense for any pairs $(X,\mathfrak{s})$ with $c_1(\mathfrak{s})|_{\partial X}$ torsion.

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated. Do you know of any places where this is discussed in a book or paper?

Comment: For your original version, most books on 4-dimensional manifolds would cover this topic. I remember that chapter 1 of Gompf-Stipsicz's 4-manifold and Kirby calculus contains this topic, maybe in integral homology sphere version (although the logic is the same), if you want me to suggest one.